# SWT browser API issue

Tags: java, browser, swt, webbrowser-control

I'm using java SWT browser component to display a web page which contains a dynamic data grid.
When I'm selecting any row, the complete grid events are disabled after that.After selection it sends a request using AJAX after which nothing can be selected or deselected.
[image: Data grid erro screenshot]

This works fine in Internet explorer. How can I resolve the issue in the browser component.
I'm using basic SWT browser component snippet.

Comment: The SWT Browser is just a wrapper around Internet Explorer / Mozilla Firefox XULRunner / Webkit depending on the platform and the style flags specified.

Answer (score 0):

You can force set the API that SWT Browser component will use. For example:

```
Browser browser = new Browser(parent, SWT.WEBKIT);
```

Note that webkit libraries should be available to JVM in order to work.

Comment: This is what I personally try first to resolve the issue, as it can help to make clear whether this a particular browser problem or an SWT one.